# Is it possible to use bigquery in aws lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, aws-lambda, google-bigquery

I want to write a python function that send data to Bigquery every time a put event occurs in my S3 bucket but I'm new in AWS is it possible to integrate bigquery with a lambda function? or can someone give me another way to stream my dynamodb data to bigquery? Thank you my language is python
N.B: I used dynamostream firehose to send my data in S3 now I want to retrieve my data from s3 every time a put event occur to send it into bigquery.

Comment: You are mentioning S3 then DynamoDB. Please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: You know bigquery is a Google proprietary service? Just making sure you're meaning to ask for a cross-cloud-provider solution? Also, this is a huge scope for a question - you'll need to break it down into a more targeted issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are already plenty of resources online about "how to trigger a lambda after a put object on a S3".

But here are a few links to get you set up:

- You will need to set up an EventBridge (CloudWatch Events are legacy) to trigger your Lambda when some action happens on your S3 bucket:
  https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/compute/using-dynamic-amazon-s3-event-handling-with-amazon-eventbridge/
- You can use the boto3 Python framework to write AWS Lambdas:
  https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html
- You can check the BigQuery Python SDK by GCP to communicate with your BQ database: https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/index.html

Comment: Use Worker identity pool to manage the authentication between AWS and Google Cloud without using the (dirty) service account key files